# Is a polycarbonate beer mug appropriate for serving alcohol?

Tags: safety, alcohols

Are polycarbonate & acrylic beer mug, whiskey glasses safe for serving alcohol? I mean does it leach or dissolve? What are the harmful effects in long run if any?

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine if used correctly! Most drinking alcohol wouldn't be strong enough to denature the polycarbonate which is very resistant anyway hence why they make whiskey/beer cups out of it. Some moonshine might warp it! Straight spirits may over time start to dissolve the polycarbonate. The harmful effects would be intoxication I'd say and maybe alcoholism !...

Answer (score 0):

There might be some question about using polycarbonate for any food contact: [*bis*-phenol A (BPA), used as a plasticizer](http://www.bisphenol-a.org/human/polyplastics.html) for a number years, has been linked to ["possible health effects of BPA on the brain, behavior and prostate gland of fetuses, infants and children."](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/nutrition-and-healthy-eating/expert-answers/bpa/faq-20058331) [Alternatives to BPA, such as *bis*-phenol S (BPS)](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/bpa-free-plastic-containers-may-be-just-as-hazardous/), may be just as toxic.

So, in short, adults *probably* have low risk from polycarbonate vessels and utensils, but you might prefer to use an alternative. Acrylic plastic, however, tends to craze from solvents, stress and even normal washing. Polyethylene, polypropylene and other plastics might be a better choice.

BTW, much of the [BPA with which we come in contact is from the thermal printing paper used for cash register receipts.](http://munews.missouri.edu/news-releases/2014/1022-thermal-paper-cash-register-receipts-account-for-high-bisphenol-a-bpa-levels-in-humans-mu-study-finds/) If you handle these continually in business, you might consider gloves or [a barrier cream.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_cream)